# Troubleshoot unresolved dependencies with UWP projects

Tags: uwp, visual-studio-2017

A project that compiles just fine on the machine on which it was created (let's call that system A) complains about unsatisfied dependencies when the entire solution is copied to another computer (B). Here are some of the many errors reported.

```
Error   CS0246  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)        PumpControlApp  C:\Users\MYPROFILE\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETCore,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs   2   Active
Error   CS0400  The type or namespace name 'System' could not be found in the global namespace (are you missing an assembly reference?) PumpControlApp  C:\Users\PWONE\AppData\Local\Temp\.NETCore,Version=v5.0.AssemblyAttributes.cs   4   Active
```

On system B I can create and compile a UWP app, so I suspect this is something along the lines of the project referencing a specific *version*, but there's no indication of version or the existence of a problem when I expand the References node of the project on system B.

In case it matters I must mention that I am targeting ARM.

Has anyone experienced this problem?

Can anyone suggest potential ways to resolve the problem?

Comment: If nothing better is offered, the brute-force solution is to create an empty new project and start copying in files and resources until it either fails or is complete.  As you do that, try copying versions back to system A and see if they fail there.

Comment: Yes, grafting code into a new project is my likely outcome, and in this case it's not onerous as all the interesting code is in the one and only form because it's actually a control process on Windows IoT on a Raspberry Pi. I raised the question because more complex projects with more dependencies are far more trouble to graft.

Comment: The exception error looks like the assembly missed , you could try delete the `bin` and `obj` folder that stored in your project then restore the nuget package. if it also does not work, please modify project target version.